# Could not connect to SMTP host, java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

When I use spring java mail send email,In the LAN test environment and the local development environment is no problem, but released to the production environment, reported the following exception:

```
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.s
    mtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
    DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.exmail.qq.com", port 465, isSSL false 
Exception in thread "Thread-18" org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.exmail.qq.com, port: 465; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error
    constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.s ecurity.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext).
```

The test environment and the production environment of the jre version are 1.8 update 121. both of windows server 2012

Comment: From your prod server, can you connect to `smtp.exmail.qq.com` host on `465` port?

Comment: since `465` is the port number you are using `ssl`, you can run `openssl s_client -crlf -connect smtp.exmail.qq.com:465` to find if `465` port is blocked

Comment: I checked that port 465 is open and not blocked.the stmp server is  the third party enterprise mailbox server.In the LAN test environment and the local development environment ,I am using this, all can send mail normally

Comment: Can you run `tracert/traceroute smtp.exmail.qq.com` from your prod server to check DNS ? Also, your prod server will be set with both inbound/outbound firewall policies. Double check with your network infra teams.

Comment: I tracert smtp server address, has some packet time out .I've already fed back to network manager..but in the LAN test server I tracert too.There are also some packets that are response timeout then also can send email

Comment: I put the 465 port to 25 port and do not use SSL when the mail can be sent normally.I guess may be the network side of the problem.Only for the time being to use non-SSL way to send mail. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad that it helped you. I told SSL to be used to debug the connectivity issues. Did networks amended the firewall rules to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the [connection debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug)?  There's probably a firewall or anti-virus preventing you from connecting.

Comment: ok.I try it..but telnet 465 is not probems. And tracert smtp server address has some packet time out

Answer (score 0):

As already said by @Bill, it is mostly network infra team's work to amend firewall inbound/outbound policies/ proxy connections/ opening firewall ports/ DNS lookup issues.

1. **To check end url connectivity via firewall rules:**

   Run `tracert/traceroute <host-name>`

   `tracert on windows OS` and `traceroute on *nix OS`.
2. **To check whether port is opened.**

   Run `telnet <host-name> <port-number>`
3. **To check proxy connections.**

   Run `ping <host-name>`
4. **To check DNS issues.**

   Run `nslookup <host-name>`

The above `nslookup` should resolve host-name to ip address. If not, you will have to add the hostname and the ip address in `hosts` file /etc/* directory.

I found these 4 techniques to be helpful for me to debug network infra issues. I might have missed many, kindly forgive me!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I learned the network debugging related to the program, I have the diagnostic results back to the network administrator, and now the first non-SSL way to send, and so there is a reply to SSL.